# How come if I use the same variable in a for loop it works (retains its value) and if I use a different one it doesn't?

Tags: python

The code should replace all the vowels with the letter p.  How come this code works.  If I input "hello" it prints "hpllp"

```
for i in word:
    if i == "a" or i == "e" or i == "i" or i == "o" or i == "u":
        word = word.replace(i, "p")
  
print(word)
```

But this doesn't? It prints out "hellp"

```
translated_word = ""
for i in word:
    if i == "a" or i == "e" or i == "i" or i == "o" or i == "u":
        translated_word = word.replace(i, "p")
    
print(translated_word)
```

TYIA

Comment: You should try to go through *exactly what is happening* with each variable using pen and paper, or using a tool like https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit to visualize what's happening

Comment: You can use  pen and paper or use the debugger this will help you alot

Comment: This isn't too difficult to understand. If you run the second code, you are never actually changing the word, so the first true iteration changes hello to hpllo, then the last true iteration changes hello to hellp. Your replace statement is only replacing one vowel in the original word at a time, but since you are assigning the modification to a subsequent variable instead of the word itself, you only get the last substitution in your print statement.

Comment: FWIW, the better way to do this is by [translating the string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate): `trans = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('aeiou', 'p')); 'hello'.translate(trans)` -> `'hpllp'`

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I sort of get it now haha, beginner things sorry hehe

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you were setting the variable "word" to itself while performing replacements.
In the second you were setting the "translated_word" variable equal to the "word" replacement but without a way for the code to remember that in between loops and being constantly overwritten as the loop went on.

Depending on the use a function can be used with fairly little change to your current code.

```
def replace(word):
    for i in word:
        if i == "a" or i == "e" or i == "i" or i == "o" or i == "u":
            word = word.replace(i, "p")
    return(word)
translated_word = replace('hello')   
print(translated_word)
```